# Determine if same pointers are passed to a macro

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-errors, static-assert

There are set of macros, for debugging, logging, stack-trace displaying etc. One of them is like:

```
#define ASSERT_IF_NULL_2(_ptr1, _ptr2) \ 
    ASSERT(_ptr1);  \
    ASSERT(_ptr2);
```

This is over simplified version of macro(s) I have written. I have custom-assertion dialog box if assertion (runtime) fails, logs such null-check failure into log file. Macros are also written such that non-pointers are checked at compile time (static-assert).

Now, I am looking for some static-assert to check if two pointers are actually same. Example:

```
int* ptr;
ASSERT_IF_NULL_2(ptr, ptr);
```

Should raise a compiler error since both arguments to macro are same. I don't care if pointers point to same memory (since that thing is runtime).

I have tried expression like:

```
int xx;
xx = 1 / (ptr-ptr);
xx = 1 / (&ptr - &ptr);
```

None of them gives divide-by-zero compiler error. 
Also, I have tried with template that takes `void*` is template argument:

```
template<void* T>
class Sample{};
```

But it doesn't allow local-variable pointers to be passed to template non-type argument.

I am using **VC9**, which doesn't support `constexpr` keyword (even VS2012 doesn't). I tried using 'const' instead, which doesnt throw error. I also used the expression as array-size, which **always** results in error.

```
int array[(&ptr - &ptr)]; // Even with ptrdiff_t
```

Comment: When you say "two pointers are actually same", what exactly do you mean? That `_ptr1` and `_ptr2` consist of the same sequence of tokens?

Comment: It means if they are actually same. foo(a,a) means these parameters are same.

Comment: `int array[(&ptr - &ptr)]; ` is a good attempt, but what if the size-expression turns out to be negative? That means, the pointers are different, hence valid, but the array declaration will result in error.

Comment: `(bool)(&ptr-&ptr)` will come to rescue. All that can be handled!

Comment: @Ajay: Yup. I was just pointing out. I know if the expression is constant (which unfortunately is not), we can make it work in many different ways.

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot pass string-literal as template argument, otherwise it was a simple problem to solve. I'm giving up for the time being. Let me know if you find some solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to check if same name is passed to both arguments, right? Then this simple trick works

```
#define ASSERT_IF_NULL_2(_ptr1, _ptr2)\
{\
    int _check_##_ptr1;\
    int _check_##_ptr2;\
}\
ASSERT(_ptr1);\
ASSERT(_ptr2);

int main ()
{
    int* ptr1;
    int* ptr2;

    ASSERT_IF_NULL_2 (ptr1, ptr1); // error: redeclaration of `int _check_ptr1'
    ASSERT_IF_NULL_2 (ptr1, ptr2); // OK
}
```

**EDIT** (By OP, Ajay):

On Visual C++ compiler, we can use MS specific keyword [`__if_exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7wy9xh3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to give error through `static-assert` :

```
 #define ASSERT_IF_NULL_2(_ptr1, _ptr2)\
    {\
        int _check_##_ptr1;\
        __if_exists(_check_##_ptr2) 
             STATIC_ASSERT(false, "Same pointer passed twice")
    }\
```

Since `static_assert` keyword doesnt exist for pre-VS2010 compilers, one may use custom-written STATIC_ASSERT.

Comment: Well, that's a good solution and will work for me. I am updating your post itself, which will utilize static-assert (Only for VC compiler).

Answer (score 5):

Alright, the solution turns out to be simple. Use `static_assert` and [Stringizing Operator (#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x.aspx):

```
#define ASSERT_TWO(a,b) static_assert((void*)#a != (void*) #b, "'" #a  "' and '" #b "' are same variables passed to ASSERT_TWO.")
```

Demo:

```
int *global;    

int main()
{
    int *local;

    ASSERT_TWO(global, local);  //should pass
    ASSERT_TWO(local, global);  //should pass

    ASSERT_TWO(global, global); //should fail
    ASSERT_TWO(local, local);   //should fail

    (void)local; //suppress unsused warning!
}
```

which results in **very helpful** error message:

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   main.cpp:18:5: error: static assertion failed: 'global' and 'global' are same variables passed to ASSERT_TWO.
>   main.cpp:19:5: error: static assertion failed: 'local' and 'local' are same variables passed to ASSERT_TWO.

[Online demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7a0c549b8e46dad2a2169770a36ce28a).

Hope that helps.

<sub>I recall that this will not help you, as you're using **VC9**, but I keep this answer as it might help others. As of now, you could use other solution which generates redeclaration error which is less helpful error message compared to the `static_assert` message.</sub>

Comment: What about `main.cpp:15:5: error: redeclaration of 'constexpr const int x'`, not to mention that I get further errors if I switch it up to `ASSERT_TWO(local, global)` which should work.

Comment: Here is a fixed version: `#define ASSERT_TWO(a, b)   {int x = 1 / (reinterpret_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(a) - reinterpret_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(b));}`. => You don't need to define the pointers as const expr, and the redifined error goes away

Comment: @ted: `int x` does NOT force the compiler to evaluate the expression on the RHS even if it can.

Comment: you are missing a semicolon before the closing `}`. Ok I see why you want to use `constexpr` but what about [this](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=09381325f50a77bebfffc0b3cee5d5b5): the value of global can not be used in `constexpr`

Comment: I am sorry. The modified solution doesnt work either. I dont get why `#p` would differ to `p` when used after `(void*)` ?

Comment: @Ajay: I'm comparing the address of the string-literal created out of `#a`, and assuming that two string-literals of same value will have same address (which is not gauranteed but works anyway).

Comment: Okay! I understood. But VC++ compiler doesn't treat it as good. Says it is not a constant expression! :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to check if the pointers point to the same memory or if they point at the same value?

In the first case

```
xx = 1 / (ptr-ptr);
```

should work.

in the second case

```
xx = 1 / (*ptr-*ptr);
```

should work.

Comment: You didn't understand the question!

Answer (score -2):

Try one of these maybe:

```
ASSERT_IF_NULL(ptr1 == ptr1);
ASSERT(ptr1 != ptr2)
```

As pointed outby Nawaz you want a compile error so try this:

```
1/(ptr1 != ptr2);
1/static_cast<int>(ptr1 != ptr2);
static_assert(ptr1 != ptr2, "Pointers are different")       //if you dont use c++0x look here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/1664651/258418
```

Comment: It wont work. And your static_assert keyword usage is wrong - it takes two parameters.

Comment: @Ajay: Did you see my attempt (before I deleted it)? It solved partly. I'm working on it. If I succeed in solving it completely, I will post it again.

Comment: I tried that, and tried to add comment: I am using VC9, which doesnt have `constexpr`. See modified post.